# How to animate when no reference to target view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiviewanimation

In my iOS5 app for iPhone I have something like this

AppDelegate
ivar ViewController1
ivar ViewController2

ViewController1
ivar view1
ivar button1
IBAction animateToView

ViewController2
ivar view2

Now I want to animate from view1 from viewcontroller1 to view2 from viewcontroller2 by pushing a button in viewcontroller1. 
Bu I do not have a reference to the view2 to the viewcontroller2 in viewcontroler1.

If i hook the button to an action/target and in it i use block based animation

```
[UIView transitionFromView:<#(UIView *)#> 
                    toView:<#(UIView *)#> 
                  duration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> 
                   options:<#(UIViewAnimationOptions)#> 
                completion:<#^(BOOL finished)completion#>]
```

I am unable to fill in the toView: because of those missing references.
What would you recommend? Is it even good to solve this by action target?

Thanks,
EarlGrey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a instance of `ViewController2`. And then pass that `view2` to the transition. Check this out -

```
ViewController2 *twoVC = [ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[UIView transitionFromView:view1 
                        toView:twoVC.view2 
                      duration:0.5 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        /* do something on animation completion */
                      }];
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't he init `ViewController2` with it's nib name?

Comment: yes, forgot to add that. I just typed this code freehand. changed it

Comment: I shouldn't. It works automatically, when I create ViewController2 class by using the Xcode wizard and check "with NIB".